# Iphone unwanted download stopping me from accessing main screen

Tags: iphone, software

I plugged in my Iphone 4 into my computer to charge it, and I believe I turned off the Itunes from coming up (not quite sure).  Anyway, when I went to take my Iphone off the charger, there is something that is now downloaded or installed on my phone that I did not ask for.

It first comes up with "Hello", then "Bonjour", then "Hola", then hello written in Chinese, and all the other languages one by one appear... Some sort of voice over thing starts happening, it starts talking in different languages.

It is preventing me from going to the main screen unless I put in my network information.  I cannot access my icon home screen.  Help!  Without installing this software, whatever the heck it is, how can I get past this.  It has different languages, asks you to select yours, then asks for your network info.  Help!!!

Comment: That sounds very much like the "Welcome to your brand new iPhone/iOS" setup screen. You should only ever see it once. Once you work your way through it & answer all the questions, it should go away. Is it not doing?

Answer (score 1):

That is the the "welcome page" after you update your iPhone. Everything is fine just do everything they say on that page and you will be good.
Now why did he updated without you knowing well the only cause I can think of is that when you connected it to your computer iTunes started the upgrade automatically.

---

If that pages looks exactly like this you're good:
[image: Welcome page after iPhone update]